# Inner product inequality

Tags: inequality, inner-products

Is there any inequality for $x^TAy$ where $x$ and $y$ are vectors and $A$ is positive definite matrix.

For example: $x^TAy\ge k||x||||y||$ where $k$ is a coefficient of (min or max) eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with the biggest (by absolute value) eigenvalue definitely works (but with $\leq$ sign, of course). You can also write a similar inequality in general for singular value decomposition.

The theorem you are looking for is the bounding of the induced matrix norm by the eigenvalues:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Induced_norm

The derivation would go as follows:

Cauchy-Schwarz:
$$x(Ay)\leq |x| |Ay|$$
Matrix norm definition ($|A|=\sup(|Ax|/|x|)$):
$$|Ay|\leq |A||x|$$
Equality:
$$|A|=\sigma_{max}(A)$$

Therefore
$$xAy\leq \sigma_{max}(A)|x||y|$$
This is true for any $A$, not just for square matrices.

Similarly, you get
$$xA^{-1}y\leq \sigma_{min}^{-1}(A)|x||y|$$
for an invertible matrix.

Comment: Thanks orion for your prompt reply. I'm just wondering if there is $\ge$ inequality (similar to the one i stated in the question) as we have for $\lambda_{max}(A)||x||^2\ge x^TAx \ge \lambda_{min}(A)||x||^2$.

Comment: In general, there is a pair of $x$ and $y$ that are orthogonal. So $0$ is your lower limit. For the square form, you could bound it by $\lambda_{min}$ because all terms in the sum are positive. But for distinct vectors, $x_i y_i$ product of components in the eigensystem can be negative, so you cannot bound your result.